# mod_was_ap22_http.so is not available on Websphere 9?

Tags: websphere, ibmhttpserver

I'm trying to integrate IBM Http Server to WAS on windows server. Webspher, IHS, Plugins, all installed on same server by installation manager, all of them are version 9 and 64bit.

Then I follow the steps on this(https://geekflare.com/integrate-http-server-with-websphere-8-5/) to start my integration, but something when wrong: I cannot find `mod_was_ap22_http.so` in my plugin folder. I when to check the folder `X:\IBM\WebSphere\Plugins\bin\64bits` and `D:\IBM\WebSphere\Plugins\bin\32bits`, I see `mod_was_ap24_http.dll` and `mod_was_ap22_http.dll` but not the `.so` that I need. I also tried to use `mod_was_ap24_http.dll` in my *httpd.conf* file but it's not working, then I got the following error

```
The IBMHTTPServer9 service is successfully installed.
Testing httpd.conf....
Errors reported here must be corrected before the service can be started.
httpd: Syntax error on line 116 of X:/IBM/HTTPServer/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot loa
d X:/IBM/WebSphere/Plugins/bin/64bits/mod_was_ap24_http.dll into server: %1 \xa4
\xa3\xacO\xa6\xb3\xae\xc4\xaa\xba Win32 \xc0\xb3\xa5\xce\xb5{\xa6\xa1\xa1C
```

Is there something that I'm not doing right?

Comment: Libraries are named dll on windows (dynamic linked libraries) instead of so so the naming is correct. I don't think IHS ships a 64 bit version on windows. Are you using your IHS installation is 64bits? I suspect you want to load the 32bit version.  My v9 IHS httpd.conf has the following configuration:

Comment: LoadModule was_ap24_module "C:\IBM\WebSphere\Plugins\bin\32bits\mod_was_ap24_http.dll"

Comment: @BetsyRiggins seem like you're right, this line did work. I also noticed in his post he said `was_app22_module ` and yours is `was_ap24_module `. He got additional 'p' in his command?

Comment: "was_app22_module" would have never worked anywhere.  I wouldn't trust much that you read in the linked guide.

Answer (score 0):

The guide is written for Linux and you're on Windows. Further, the guide has typos in configuration files.  I'd suggest following the official docs and running PCT/WCT instead of manually configuring all of this.

Answer (score 0):

Just add mentioned module:

[root@172 bin]# locate mod_was_ap22_http.so

Go to location:

/opt/IBM/HTTPServer/conf

vim http.conf

(add mentioned below module)

LoadModule was_ap22_module /opt/IBM/WebSphere/Plugins/bin/64bits/mod_was_ap22_http.so

./apachectl -k start